# Get json info direct back from post request

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, json

Im trying to make a simple login system with php + a mysql database / java for android.
For communication between both im using Json.

I've the php code here: (A simple example of what i wanna archieve).

```
    <?php
     include("../dbfunctions.php");

    class mobilelogin{
    private $user;
    private $pass;

    public function getData(){
        $get->user = $_POST['user'];
        $get->pass = $_POST['pass'];
        return $get;
    }
    public function getDbData($user){
        $dbfunctions = new dbfunctions;
        $getvalue = $this->getData();
        return $dbfunctions->returnUser($user); // get pass by user
    }
    public function md5convert($user){
        return md5($this->getDbData($user)); // convert this pass to md5
    }
    public function check(){ // check everthing here
        $getvalue = $this->getData();
        if(isset($getvalue->user) && isset($getvalue->pass)) // everthing filled in
        {
            return "valid";
        }else{
            return "invalid";
        }

    }
    public function response(){ // show data here in json format
        echo json_encode(array('result' => $this->check()));
    }

}
   header("Content-Type: text/json");
   $mobilelogin = new mobilelogin;
   echo $mobilelogin->response();
?>
```

Like you see, im trying just a simple json post example,
my result in json is this: `{ result:invalid }`
As you see, if the php code receives the post values from java it should display valid otherwise invalid.

Now i've this android code, which does a post request:

```
public void login(View v) throws ClientProtocolException, URISyntaxException, IOException, JSONException
    {       

        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(processUrl);

        try {
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
               nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user", uservalidated));
               nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pass", passvalidated));

               httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
               client.execute(httppost);

               Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Everthing well.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.e("testnow", response());
    }
```

This does the post request fired when you click the login button, and the php server should receive it,
Like you see the Log (`Log.e("testnow", response());`) is the function to receive the data by httpget , this function:

```
public String response() throws URISyntaxException, ClientProtocolException, IOException, JSONException{

    HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
    request.setURI(new URI(processUrl));
    HttpResponse response;

    response = client.execute(request);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response
            .getEntity().getContent()));

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    String line;
    while((line=in.readLine())!=null)
    {

        builder.append(line);
    }
    String JSONdata = builder.toString();
    JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(JSONdata);
    String JSONresponse = jObject.getString("result");


    return JSONresponse;
}
```

This displays invalid from the json output. But it should display valid, when i ticked in both username and password, but it won't update.

I hope you understand my question, and all help is welcome.
Also if this isn't the right method to make a login system this way, also share please.

Answer (score 2):

Though I am an Android App Developer and I have solved so many problems as you said. As per my early view I think there is no problem in Android end, it's the problem in PHP end. In your Server side code data is not updated by this code. Please verify your code. Please look this code of PHP side , in this way you can create as well as updated the code.

```
<?php
/*
 * Following code will create a new profile row
 * All profile details are read from HTTP Post Request
 */
// array for JSON response
$response = array();
// check for required fields
if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['mobile']) && isset($_POST['gender'])&& isset($_POST['location'])  && isset($_POST['image']) && isset($_POST['fb_user']) && (trim($_POST['name']) != '') && (trim($_POST['email']) != '')  &&  (trim($_POST['mobile']) != '')  &&  (trim($_POST['gender']) != '')  &&  (trim($_POST['location']) != '')  &&  (trim($_POST['image']) != '')  ) {

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $mobile = $_POST['mobile'];
    $gender = $_POST['gender'];
    $country = $_POST['country'];
    $location = $_POST['location'];
    $image = $_POST['image'];
    $fb_user = $_POST['fb_user'];
    if($fb_user == '0'){
        $pin = $_POST['pin'];
    } else{
        $pin = '0';
    }
    $created_date = date("Ymd");
    $created_date2 = time();
    $binary=base64_decode($image);
    // binary, utf-8 bytes

    // include db connect class
    require_once  'db_connect.php';
    // connecting to db
    $db = new DB_CONNECT();

    $chk_existing_user = "SELECT * FROM `user_profile` WHERE `email` ='".$email."'";
    $res_existing_user = mysql_query($chk_existing_user);
    $num_rows_existing_user = mysql_num_rows($res_existing_user); //checking for existing user

   // mysql inserting a new row
    header('Content-Type: image/jpg; charset=utf-8');
    $username_arr = explode("@",$email);
    $username = $username_arr[0].'_'.$created_date;
    $file_name = 'user_images/'.$username.'.jpg';
    $file = fopen($file_name, 'wb');
    fwrite($file, $binary);
    fclose($file);

    if($num_rows_existing_user == 0){
        $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `user_profile`(name,  email, mobile, gender, country, location, image, pin, fb_user, created_date ) VALUES('$name', '$email' , '$mobile', '$gender' , '$country', '$location' , '$file_name', '$pin', '$fb_user', '$created_date')");
        $inserted_edited = '1';
    }else{
        $result = mysql_query("UPDATE `user_profile` SET name='$name', mobile ='$mobile', gender ='$gender', country='$country', location ='$location', image = '$file_name', pin = '$pin', fb_user ='$fb_user', created_date ='$created_date2' WHERE email = '$email'");
        $inserted_edited = '2';
    }
    // check if row inserted or not
    if ($inserted_edited == '1') {
        // successfully inserted into database
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "profile successfully created!";
        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else if($inserted_edited == '2') {
        // failed to insert row
        $response["success"] = 2;
        $response["message"] = "profile updated successfully!";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else {
    // required field is missing
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "required field(s) is missing!";
    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

If my answer will help you then don't forget to support my answer. 
:)

Enjoy!!!

Comment: Thnx, i will look again into it, but now on the php side!

Comment: Ok, and let me inform please.

Comment: This is not really anything else then i did. But i changed some things, I use now my check() as base which does encode the result, instead of the response function. I was thinking it didn't do the $_POST maybe if i did it in response. But it still doesn't work... Idk if it receives the $_POST at all, but i've another example code where it just works..